# How to test own image in geoff hinton's deep neural network?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, object-recognition, deep-learning

[Here is the link for Geoff Hinton's Matlab code.](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/MatlabForSciencePaper.html)
He has made this code for handwriting recognition.
I want an object recognition code, so I want to train it with my own image. I am doing it by making few changes (loading my own image data-sets instead of `digit0.mat`) in `makebatches.m` file.
But I am not able to find after training it, that from **where to test the created neural network** in my own way?
Can someone please help by looking into the code?

Comment: What is the objective of your exercise? You can probably do pre-training of the network with your image, but for fine-tuning the network you would need different kinds images with different labels. And literature suggests that you need to have lot of training data for the deep architectures to perform well.

Comment: yes and i have trained my neural network with my own image data and my own label but this code only re-generates the numbers, what i want to do is, after training it, give it an image and it could identify what the object is. I am also looking for bigger image database managed only 300-400 images of each object to train... anyway thanks for getting back to me @StrikeR